# Remove POI Marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openstreetmap, geocoding, react-leaflet

Is there a way to deactivate these "POI markers"? For my use it is not relevant to show local restaurants, stores and public facilities, so I would like to hide them.

[image: Example Image of London, United Kingdom]

How can I do that? I'm using `react-leaflet`. Many thanks in advance!

I have already done some research but have not found a way to deactivate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you haven't really explained to us which OSM-based map you are using but this looks like raster tiles. Raster tiles can't be customized. However, you can switch to a different tile provider (check [Leaflet Provider Demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) for various examples) and choose a style which shows POIs less prominently.
Alternatively, switch to vector tiles where you have more control about the style of the map.